# Calculating elapsed time in R given one column

Tags: r

I currently have data that has one column of dates and times (in POSIXct format already) and a column showing the "ON/OFF" state of a data logger.  I need to calculate the time elapsed between the OFF (0) and ON (1) states to calculate delay.

Data looks like this:

```
onoff            datetime
1     1 2014-05-14 16:26:57
2     0 2014-05-14 16:27:02
3     1 2014-05-14 16:27:06
4     0 2014-05-14 16:27:12
5     1 2014-05-14 16:28:10
6     0 2014-05-14 16:28:15
```

I am struggling with how to do this calculation.  In Excel, I created an if-then statement to subtract each row from the previous row given a "0" condition for the ON/OFF variable.

I think the best way to do this in R may be to create 2 new columns, each corresponding to the subset when onoff =1 or 0.  How can I do this?  If I can create two columns, it will be much easier to calculate using the timediff function (and can rule out NA or very large values).  Thanks for your help, I am very new at this but haven't found an answer to my specific problem via Google or other help sites.

Answer (score 3):

Of these solutions (3) is particularly short and also flexibly specifies the fill value as NA or 0 based on the value of the `fill` variable.

**1) ave** Revised in light of poster's comment to add differences to original data.frame.  `cumsum(onoff)` is `c(1, 1, 2, 2, ...)` and `ave` performs `diff` on each group creating
a vector the same length as the prior two `ave` arguments.

```
transform(DF, elapsed = ave(as.numeric(datetime), cumsum(onoff), FUN = diff))
```

The result is:

```
  onoff            datetime elapsed
1     1 2014-05-14 16:26:57       5
2     0 2014-05-14 16:27:02       5
3     1 2014-05-14 16:27:06       6
4     0 2014-05-14 16:27:12       6
5     1 2014-05-14 16:28:10       5
6     0 2014-05-14 16:28:15       5
```

**2) dplyr** Using dplyr we could alternately write the following which gives similar output to the above:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(onoff)) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(elapsed = diff(as.numeric(datetime))) %>%
  select(- grp)
```

**2a)** An alternate dplyr solution is.  This lets us specify the `fill` value as NA or 0:

```
> fill <- NA
> DF %>% mutate(elapsed = as.numeric(datetime - lag(datetime)) * c(fill, 1))
  onoff            datetime elapsed
1     1 2014-05-14 16:26:57      NA
2     0 2014-05-14 16:27:02       5
3     1 2014-05-14 16:27:06      NA
4     0 2014-05-14 16:27:12       6
5     1 2014-05-14 16:28:10      NA
6     0 2014-05-14 16:28:15       5
```

**3)**  This just used plain `diff` and together with 3a seems shortest of the solutions.  Use `fill` from above:

```
transform(DF, elapsed = c(fill, diff(as.numeric(datetime))) * c(fill, 1))
```

This gives a similar result to 2a.

**3a)** This is the same as the last one except it fills with zeros.

```
transform(DF, elapsed = c(0, diff(as.numeric(datetime))) * !onoff)
```

**4)** In this solution we fill with zero:

```
transform(DF, elapsed = as.numeric(datetime - rep(datetime[onoff == 1], each=2)))
```

giving:

```
  onoff            datetime elapse
1     1 2014-05-14 16:26:57      0
2     0 2014-05-14 16:27:02      5
3     1 2014-05-14 16:27:06      0
4     0 2014-05-14 16:27:12      6
5     1 2014-05-14 16:28:10      0
6     0 2014-05-14 16:28:15      5
```

**5)** @thelatemail has provided an alternative in the comments.

Next time please provide sample output to clarify your question.

`DF` is:

```
DF <- structure(list(onoff = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
  datetime = structure(c(1400099217, 1400099222, 1400099226, 1400099232, 
   1400099290, 1400099295), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), 
  .Names = c("onoff", "datetime"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**ADDED** Several alternative solutions.

Comment: `with(DF, datetime[onoff==0] - datetime[onoff==1])` would be an alternative implementation.

Comment: I believe this outputs the time difference, but I really need it the time difference calculation results as a column in the original table (for time series analysis).

Comment: Just to clarify, the data I gave was a small example--I have about 3,000 observations total and this will need to work for additional data as it is updated from the field.

Comment: I think saving your original answer to a subset of DF would be more readable: `dat$elapsed <- 0; dat$elapsed[dat$onoff==0] <- with(dat, datetime[onoff==0] - datetime[onoff==1]);`